# rtabmap, rviz: data disappearing, flickering

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running rtabmap and I have problem that some parts of the map flickering in rviz;

here is video that shows my problem: https://yadi.sk/i/roougyDK8XWkSA

on 21st second and on 1m3s you can observe that everything behind my mobile robot disappears, and some part shows again at 2m8s.

why is this happening? where is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339685/rtabmap,-rviz:-data-disappearing,-flickering/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks that memory management is enabled and the processing time is high enough to make "forgetting" old parts of the map. What are the parameters used for rtabmap node? Set `Rtabmap/TimeThr` to 0 to disable memory management.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-16**:
thanks! it was 700

here is the parameters: https://pastebin.com/hyHKNsBc

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-16**:
also, can you help me with this problem? its not about rtabmap, about global planning
https://answers.ros.org/question/339249/movement-without-stopping-on-move_base-goals/